# iOS Populate table with mutablearray data

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I have a JSON file: http://astrodeer.com.au/ingredients.php which has been been parsed in. I created two NSMutableArrays, one for the ingredients and one for the ratings for each product listed.

First of all I have populated my first table with the product name/brand:

[image: First table view]

When a user clicks on an item, it takes them to this page where I am attempting to populate the table with the ingredient names and their corresponding ratings.

[image: Second Table]

This is what I have so far. I am getting an error at "numberOfRowsInSection"

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'"

Ideally I am going to change the UIImage depending on the rating number using an if statement. But at the moment I am struggling to work out how to get the ingredient name to display.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section {

    return [_selectedProduct.ingredientsArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ingredientsCell";

    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UILabel *ingLabel = (UILabel *)[myCell viewWithTag:1];
    UIImage *ingRating = (UIImage *)[myCell viewWithTag:2];

    ingLabel.text = _selectedProduct.ingredientsArray[indexPath.row];

    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the error at `numberOfRowsInSection`? By the code it looks more like you could get an error in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Although the above code should work fine, unless you're changing the ingredients array somewhere which removes the last element.

Comment: why not place a break point on the prepare for segue on the first VC and inspect the array's contents in the debugger console. That will give you an idea of what is really being passed on to the second VC.

Comment: Is the child array mutable too? have you initialized the mutable child array?

Comment: I put a break point at the segue and it is passing both arrays content (16 objects in each for the first selected), [link](http://i.imgur.com/3vCF6Uj.png)  I haven't modified the array so I am not sure

Comment: Given that `ingredientsArray` has 16 items, it doesn't seem that it relates to your exception message (which is referring to a 4 element array).   Have you set an exception breakpoint to confirm where the exception is ocurring?